# Dependency Resolution error Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maven, android-architecture-components

I am building a chat application in native android

I get this errors when i try to run my project -

........

```
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and viewmodel-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$1 found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2 found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$3 found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-core-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$1 found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-core-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-core-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-core-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.Observer found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-core-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations$1 found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations$2 found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations$2$1 found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and livedata-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and viewmodel-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and viewmodel-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and viewmodel-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and viewmodel-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStore found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and viewmodel-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)
Duplicate class android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner found in modules extensions-1.0.0-beta1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1) and viewmodel-1.1.1-runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1)
```

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

.........

My App level gradle file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

/**
 * This is a part of ChatApp Project (https://github.com/h01d/ChatApp)
 * Licensed under Apache License 2.0
 *
 * @author Raf (https://github.com/h01d)
 * @version 1.1
 * @since 27/02/2018
 */

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.namandevloper.satyampublic"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //https://github.com/square/picasso (Apache License 2.0)
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    //https://github.com/square/okhttp (Apache License 2.0)
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    //https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView (Apache License 2.0)
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
    //https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel (Apache License 2.0)
    implementation 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.4'
    //https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-process-button (MIT)
    implementation 'com.github.XunMengWinter:CircularAnim:0.3.4'
    //https://github.com/XunMengWinter/CircularAnim (No license)
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.8'
    //https://github.com/florent37/DiagonalLayout (Apache License 2.0)
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    //https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView (Apache License 2.0)
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    //https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout (Apache License 2.0)
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
    //https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout (Apache License 2.0)
    implementation 'me.jahirfiquitiva:FABsMenu:1.1.1'
    //https://github.com/jahirfiquitiva/FABsMenu (Apache License 2.0)
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project level Gradle -

```
/**
 * This is a part of ChatApp Project (https://github.com/h01d/ChatApp)
 * Licensed under Apache License 2.0
 *
 * @author  Raf (https://github.com/h01d)
 * @version 1.1
 * @since   27/02/2018
 */

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What should i do? I have searched and tried a lot of things but none of them helped me.

Comment: Could you please migrate your project to Androidx first. That should help.

From Refactor > Migrate to Androidx.

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much, this fixed it

Comment: That's good. After migrating, please take a look at your build.gradle file. If that helped, could you please mark the answer as accepted, so that others would benefit from it. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrating the Project to **Androidx** should help.

It can be done from:

Android Studio > Refactor > Migrate to Androidx

Comment: super bro 1 like